# Why Spacy api version and web version results are different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy for pos_ tags (parts of speech tags) and Here is my very simple approach :

```
import spacy
model=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

for i in model('I want so sit on Dining table set.'):
    print((i,i.pos_))
```

output is:

```
(I, 'PRON')
(want, 'VERB')
(so, 'ADV')
(sit, 'VERB')
(on, 'ADP')
(Dining, 'PROPN')
(table, 'NOUN')
(set, 'VERB')
(., 'PUNCT')
```

Now if i go to [web version](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=I%20want%20so%20sit%20on%20Dining%20table%20set.&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=1) of spacy and give same query then  i am getting something like this :

[image]

Why `Dining` is `PROPN` in import version model but in web version its `Noun` .

My confusion is here when both model are same then why i am not getting web version result? web-version result is more correct and that is my expected output.

If i am getting right then the reason is web-version is going through many queries daily and that's why its updating its weights from those queries and that's why its more smart ? or my hypothesis doesn't make any sense?

I thought using bs4 or selenium with phanthon for using result of web-version but that's not correct way. How i can acheive web-version result ?

Comment: It is obvious that web version will be smarter than your local version. It is a cloud version and updated everyday.

Comment: @Sraw yes but in cloud version pos_ are already define and my question is why 'Dining' is 'Pronoun' in local version but on web-version its 'Noun' ?

Comment: In web-version `Dining table` but not `Dining` is `Noun`. Because it was updated and learnt that `Dining table` is a proper noun. That is similar like `Stanford University` won't be treated as `Stanford` and `University`.

Comment: Don't think there's anything to do with `nltk` here, so removing the tag ;P

Comment: @alvas nltk is also nlp module 0_o

Comment: But it's really remotely related... -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`en_core_web_sm` is the default and smallest english model.
Web version might be using the bigger model
`en_core_web_md`.
Try with that, you will get similar results. The bigger the model, the higher is the accuracy.
List of available models here :
https://spacy.io/usage/models#available

Comment: but that web version is also showing en_core_web_sm . Now ?

Comment: Agreed, apart from model, it could be collapse phrases & collapse punctuation flags too.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on Settings at the top right corner and disable Collapse Phrases and Collapse Punctuation and you'll get the same result[image]